# Why angular cli --outputHashing=all doesn't process svg images?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I'm trying to have cache-busting in angular application. But can't get images and translation files with hashes.

Previously I had webpack configuration, and didn't use angular cli. Now i'm trying to achieve something close to my webpack configuration w/o need to have both webpack & angular cli tasks separation and running both during build process.

`angular cli --outputHashing=all` Doesn't adds hashes to images, and translation files. 
CSS,JS files have hashes.

What is the purpose of `media` or `all` values of outputHashing if it's not really `all` (images )

---

Probably I don't have images connected properly?:

I have my images in `src/assets` folder. In my project I use only svg images.
Registering them in one file, all the pathes goes like that:
`const myIcon = { myIcon: 'assets/imgs/pages/overview/img.svg' }`

Next I use it like that `<mat-icon svgIcon="myIcon"></mat-icon>`

Comment: I have same issue and I could not find any solution yet.